# Exchange online mark email as spam from a legitimate address?

Tags: exchange, outlook, microsoft-forefront

A client of us, working for a college, is using his work email to send us questions regarding a SharePoint implementation we have done. A couple of weeks ago we stopped recieving emails from him and instead got emails from quarantine@messaging.microsoft.com saying that we have a new spam message (with a big delay).

It is clearly not a spam message as all emails have different content, sent to 3-4 recipients about once a week.

Is there a setting in the BPOS admin panel or something that we can set so that Microsoft does not mark this as spam (the address is the safe sender list already on my local pc/outlook)?

Comment: You have SPF and SenderID properly configured for the domain?

Comment: There's a LOT more to spam filtering than just checking the sender's address.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a **Policy** in the admin interface that has an **Action** of **Allow**. You can set up Filters for which kind of mail you want the Policy to be effective.